# Automatically updating a formula to read from a different cell as value is entered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to run a simple formula:

```
=(W19*0.855)-X8
```

I want to know if there is a way to write a formula so that instead of having to update the X# everyday to the next row # (for instance today I updated it from X7 to X8).

The cells that I would want to formula to look at is X4:X18 but only calculate the bottom (recent) number.

Comment: Just use dollar sign and put the value in a cell of your choosing, when the formula gets pulled down it will always take the cell value you chose. for examples `=(W19*0.855)-$X$1` - so when you edit the x1 it will apply to all the formulas - if you understand?

Comment: The question is confusing. Either you want to reference the last populated cell in column `X` as it grows, or a cell that shifts down each day regardless of the number of populated cells in column `X`?

Comment: It's a tracking sheet.  So everyday I am entering new values according to what day it.  I don't want to delete any old data - that's the primary purpose of the tracking.  I only want to see how many we need to reach a goal.  I want to pass this along to someone who is unfamiliar with Excel formulas and want to make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: For instance, Say today my number is 500 tomorrow in the cell below it my new number is entered as 515.  I want the formula to automatically read that there is a new number 515 and provide me the remaining number needed.

Comment: Danny James - I'm not looking to create another spreadsheet I just want a single box with remainder needed for goal.  The tracking portion is my main focus this is just a happy extra I want to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference the last cell in column `X`:

```
=(W19*0.855)-INDEX(X:X, COUNTA(X:X))
```

The user can enter a new value each day in a new row in column `X` and the formula will foe it immediately. I requires though that all cel are populated until the last cell. Put some header title in `X1` and ask the user to enter each day a value starting from `X2`.

You can avoid some anomalies i.e. if the user leaves some cells blank, by using the following *array formula* that will always catch the last numeric cell in column X regadless of emty cells or anything else:

```
=(W19*0.855)-INDEX(X:X, MAX(ROW(X:X)*ISNUMBER(X:X)))    Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

Comment: @KittySummer funny I was addressing that possibility while you were typing your comment. Indeed in that case you should use the second option. I doesn't care where you start, or if you leave blank cells, it just captures the *last number* from column X.